# Difference between View and ImageView when outputting an image

Tags: android, view, imageview

When I output the image,I use View:

`View.setbackgroundResource()`

instead of ImageView:

`ImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)`

I was wondering if there was a big difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is a difference.

In the first one, you are modifying the BACKGROUND of a certain View.
In the second one, you are modifying the CONTENT (which is an Image) of a certain ImageView.

It might seem the same thing if the ImageView is inside (or over) the other View and if they have the same size, but usually, they are very different.

Hope this helps !